# Gentoo install multiple packages in one command

Tags: gentoo

Is it possible to install all sub packages within a specific package in a single command.

Something along the lines of "emerge sys-apps/*" (obviously this doesn't work it is just an example to help get my point across) to install all packages within the sys-apps package.

Comment: JFYI, `sys-app` is a _category_, not a _package_ %)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.
You can have a *set* w/ desired packages, or simply substitute a result of another command as parameters to `emerge` -- e.g. smth like:

```
$ emerge $(find /usr/portage/sys-apps -maxdepth 1 -type d | tail -n +2 | sed 's,/usr/portage/,,')
```